# Cannot leave iOS 12 beta testing program on iPad

Tags: ipad, configuration-profiles, beta, ios

I installed the iOS 12 Beta Software Profile on my 9.7 iPad 2017 a few months ago. I got a notification today that iOS 12.1 beta is available for download, which I did not want to install, so I went to Settings to uninstall the beta profile, but the Profiles setting is simply not there:

[image: missing Profiles setting]

What should I do to get the option back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up **downloading the beta profile again** from [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/), **deleting it** and **restarting the device**. This made the beta update notification disappear.

For some reason, the notification badge did not disappear, so it still shows that there is an update available - both in General/Software Update and next to the app icon.